# A random variable being a combination of two Gaussian random variables

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose Y and Z are independent Gaussian random variables. Then, say, the random variable X has 50% chance of taking the value of Y and 50% chance of taking the value of Z. What's the distribution of X? Is it still Gaussian?

Comment: What have you tried?  Where did you run into difficulties?  What have you read?  Which websites or books?

Comment: David gives a good point: You can calculate the CDF $P[X\leq x]$ yourself directly by the law of total probability (then differentiate to get PDF).  As in the Robert Israel answer, you should condition on an (independent) coin flip. You might also draw $f_X(x)$ for the case when $E[Y]=0$ and $E[Z]=1$ to see what it looks like.

Answer (score 4):

Presumably the event that you choose $Y$ is independent of $Y$ and $Z$, i.e. you have $X = B Y + (1-B) Z$ where $B$ is Bernoulli-$1/2$ and independent of $Y$ and $Z$.

If $Y$ and $Z$ have the same distribution, then this has the same distribution as $Y$ and $Z$.  If they don't, then it is not Gaussian.  Its pdf, cdf, and moments are the averages of those of $Y$ and of $Z$.

See [Mixture distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution)